# error Couldn't find package "@icons/material@^0.2.4" required by "react-color@^2.13.8" on the "npm" registry

Tags: installation, yarnpkg

**When i do 'yarn install' i get this below error:**

Error message:

```
yarn install v1.12.3
info No lockfile found.
[1/4] Resolving packages...
warning Resolution field "react@16.4.1" is incompatible with requested version "react@15"
**error Couldn't find package "@icons/material@^0.2.4" required by "react-color@^2.13.8" on the "npm" registry.**
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: When I do 'yarn install' it throws this error:

"error Couldn't find package "@icons/material@^0.2.4" required by "react-color@^2.13.8" on the "npm" registry."

Answer (score 0):

Doing this resolved my issue:
npm config set @icons:registry https://registry.npmjs.org/

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have any other .npmrc or .yarnrc file in your root folders. It might override your project's configurations when you do a yarn install. Worked for me when I removed these files from my other directories